# Django filter queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Django framework has a product model with about ten values that need to be filtered (color, type..). I'm trying to create a filter like this:
views:
`

```
class FilterCctvView(QuerySetsFromCctv, ListView):
    paginate_by = 32
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Cam.objects.filter(
                                Q(maker__in = self.request.GET.getlist("maker")) | 
                                Q(type_of_cam__in = self.request.GET.getlist("type_of_cam"))
        )
        return queryset
```

`in html:`

```
  <form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method = 'GET'>
            <ul> 
                <p><strong>Manufacturers</strong></p>
                {% for cam in view.get_cctv_makers %}
                    <li>    
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="maker" value="{{cam.maker}}">
                        <span>{{cam.maker}}</span>
                    </li> 
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
            <ul>
                <p><strong>Type of cameras</strong></p>
            
                {% for cam in view.get_cctv_type %}
                    <li>    
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="type_of_cam" value="{{cam.type_of_cam}}">
                        <span>{{ cam.type_of_cam}}</span>
                    </li> 
                {% endfor %} 
            </ul> 
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit">Find</button>  
        </form>
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXHxK.png)

But the filter doesn't work correctly, when I select more than two option
How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What does "doesn't work correctly mean"?

Comment: when I select sort by multiple values, the set returns data that should not be included! In db data is correct. Perhaps there is an alternative way to sort such data? thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.